# File transfer in C - Linux

Tags: c, linux, file

I'm trying to transfer a file from server to client. I first send the name of the file I want to receive to the server, the server opens the file and writes its contents into a buffer and sends it back to the client. The client then copies the contents of that buffer into a newly created file to duplicate the contents of the server file.

When *"Receive.txt"* is created, only the FIRST word of the file I opened is copied into the file I created. Where am I going wrong?

server.c sending part:

```
if(checkCommand){               
    char *tmp = buf + 4;
    char data[MAX_BLOCK_SIZE];
    FILE *fp;

    printf("File name: %s\n", tmp);
    fp = fopen(tmp, "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("File not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }
            
    do{
        fscanf(fp, "%s", buf);
        nw = write(sd, buf, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE);
    } while(fscanf(fp, "%s", buf) != EOF);
```

}

client.c receiving part:

```
else if(getCommand){
    FILE *fp;
            
    write(sd, buf, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE);
    read(sd, buf, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE);
    fp = fopen("receive.txt", "w");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "%s", buf);
}
```

Comment: The loop where you send data, you read words *twice* each iteration, discarding every second of them.

Comment: ^^^^ that `do-while` should be a simple `while (fscanf(fp, "%s", buf) != EOF)` . There should be no read within the loop body.

Comment: Other issues: On the server side `write` is sending `MAX_BLOCK_SIZE` each time regardless of how much `fscanf` really reads. On the client side there is only a single `read` so of course it will not get all the data from the server which is sent in a loop.

Comment: There are also many other problems, like you unconditionally sending `MAX_BLOCK_SIZE` bytes, no matter the length of the string. Or on the receiving side where you will very likely only receive a single word, and then treat it as a null-terminated string even if it's not. And not to mention the lack of error checking in general.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So should I use strlen(buf) instead of sending MAX_BLOCK_SIZE bytes?

Comment: Are you aware that you will not be able to transmit binary files if you use string functions?

Comment: I wouldn't use `fscanf` to read from the source file. It is too much dependant on the specific contents of the file; `%s` specifier, for example, stops acquiring at the first whitespace character, that wouldn't be consumed and would also prevent the subsequent fscanf to acquire any further string. I would rather just use **`fread`** reading a block of N characters, passing to the following write its return value (after checking for any error).

Comment: @Gerhardh I am aware of that, and I was going to ask about that in a separate question. Is there a way I can do the file transfer for both text and binary files?

Comment: Sure, don't use `fscanf`. Use `read` instead. And instead of a fixed buffer size, use the number of bytes received by `read` to write to the socket/file.

Comment: Or in your case where you have a `FILE*` you need `fread`.

Comment: @Gerhardh So ive redone my code to use fwrite and fread, and finally my file is copied into the client directory successfully. I only have the issue of identifying when its a binary file, and im also getting some invalid characters in my copied file. About to post a new question about that. Thank you all for your help

Comment: Why bother with identifying binary or text? Just handle all files as binary. You should open your files in binary mode. Otherwise there could be some unintented conversion between `\n` and `\r\n` on some systems

Comment: @Gerhardh So i open it like `fopen(filename, "rb")`? And what about when I am creating the new file like `fopen=("newfile.txt", "wb")`, how do I specify the name of the file if i dont know whether it is a binary or text file? Do I just use "newfile" instead of "newfile.txt"?

Comment: You take the name that you initially sent to the server. It could also be "newfile.log", "newfile.csv", "newfile.xml" or any other name for text files.

Comment: don't mix `stdio` (fread, etc) with raw I/O.    Just use the latter.

Comment: Don't use scanf.  The server does not need to parse the data that it reads.  Either use fgetc/fputc, or read large blocks with fread/fwrite.  There is absolutely no reason to complicate this with scanf.  (Avoiding scanf is almost always the right thing to do, anyway).

Comment: `man sendfile`  .

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I've made a lot of progress using fread and fwrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly reported in comments section, the core of your issue consists in `fscanf()` being called both for reading data and for detecting `EOF` in order to quit the loop. But the latter actually consume data as well!

If I execute your program passing the following input file

```
Yesterday
All my troubles seemed so far away
Now it looks as though they're here to stay
```

and printing the output to `stdout` with `printf("%s\n", buf);` (instead of pushing data to a socket), that's what I get:

```
Yesterday
my
seemed
far
Now
looks
though
here
stay
```

So I get not only the first word, but one every two words.

Furthermore you write to the socket `MAX_BLOCK_SIZE` bytes whatever is the number of valid bytes you correctly read from file, so `buf` will contain `MAX_BLOCK_SIZE - strlen(buf)` bytes of garbage.

This sending loop will fix most of the issues mentioned above:

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s", buf) != EOF)
{        
    write(sd, buf, strlen(buf));
}
```

Please note how you still would have something to care about:

1. are we sure that all words fit a `MAX_BLOCK_SIZE` big buffer? A word logger than the block will cause out of bound access (and **undefined behavior**), so a way to limit the number of acquired characters should be implemented
2. are we sure that all the data is sent in one shot? Probably yes, as the words are relatively short, but generally speaking the return value of the `write()` function should be checked, and if it is different from the amount of data to be sent the code should manage a way to send the remainder (or even exit the loop if the return value is negative!)

I'm not going to address these issues in this answer, but it was correct mentioning them. What I would like to emphatize, istead, is that sending data in this way will generate an output *without* whitespaces_. Something like:

```
YesterdayAllmytroublesseemedsofarawayNowitlooksasthoughthey'reheretostay
```

Even assuming that you need just a text file transfer, **probably it is not what you want**. For this reason I suggest implementing a binary trasfer using [`fread()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) in this way

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_BLOCK_SIZE 1024

char buf[MAX_BLOCK_SIZE];

int main(void)
{
    char tmp[] = "srcFile.txt";
    FILE * fp;
    int rd;
    
    printf("File name: %s\n", tmp);
    
    fp = fopen(tmp, "rb");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }
            
    while(( rd = fread(buf, 1, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE, fp)) > 0)
    {
        write(sd, buf, rd);
        //printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
    // You can call feof() or ferror() in order to discover if either EOF or an error occurred
    
    return 0;
}
```

Uncommenting the `printf` what I get is exactly the input file. Please note how it would not necessary, on Linux environment, to select the binary mode with `b`, as

> The mode string can also include the letter 'b' either as a last character or as a character between the characters in any of the two-character strings described above. **This is strictly for compatibility with C89 and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on all POSIX conforming systems, including Linux.** (Other systems may treat text files and binary files differently, and adding the 'b' may be a good idea if you do I/O to a binary file and expect that your program may be ported to non-UNIX environments.)

(the **emphasis** is mine).

---

Just some notes about the *receiver* part:

1. I cannot comment the initial `write(sd, buf, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE);` because I'm not sure about the detais of your application, but it look strange. Make sure to send consistent data, in any case.
2. **Always check the return values of `read` and `write`!** Not only they can fail (and the error, that you can get querying **`errno`**, must be properly managed) but they can also read/write from/to socket less bytes than requested
3. In the general case of a binary file, writing data to the output file with `fprintf(fp, "%s", buf);` is not safe, as `buf` could contain bytes that are not printable or, even worse, it won't be NULL-terminated. Be aware that binary data could contain the `'\0'` character inside it, and that would result in an unexpected truncation. Use [`fwrite()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite), instead.

Comment: Very well detailed answer. I appreciate this very much thank you